# Java instance creation with object as parameter

Tags: garbage-collection, parameter-passing, weak-references

When i create an object of a class which accepts object as a parameter 
for Example

```
GarbageCollected gc= new GarbageCollected();
WeakReference<GarbageCollected> reference = new WeakReference<GarbageCollected>()(gc);
```

So here how does the reference 'gc' works internally while one creates the object of 'WeakReference' class with "gc' as the argument.

Comment: When you pass a reference to an object as an argument to a constructor, it works the same as passing any value to a method’s or constructor’s parameter. The code inside the method or constructor may store that reference to a field of the object or not. That’s the basics you should have understood before ever dealing with things like `WeakReference`.

Comment: @Holger what i wanted to understand is how the referencing happens and if one is unreferenced that it is subjected to null then what about the objects holding a reference to the nullified object.

Comment: What do you mean with “how the referencing happens”? Further, do you understand that `WeakReference` is special and hence, not an example of “create an object of a class which accepts object as a parameter”? There is no such thing like a “nullified object”.